# I want to build a world from the 1940's

Tags: social-norms

I have a question for a new person when it comes to world building. I am a World War II writer and I have an idea to make a world where it is basically in the 1940's type of time period on a different planet. How could I frame it so the reader knows this is a fantasy world but not change it so much that the readers are lost and wondering what's going on, who's good and who's bad that sort of thing.

Comment: Welcome to the site Steven, please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] At the moment your question is not a question so much as the start of a long conversation. Here we have a one question/one best answer model to adhere to, so we need to stear away from the very broad and opinion based. You can [edit] to fit our paradigm, feel free to ask as many questions as needed.

Comment: Hint: consider the very successful Quentin Tarantino film [*Inglourious Basterds*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglourious_Basterds). The action takes place in 1941, in occupied France, but it eventually becomes *obvious* that it is *not* our 1941. (I won't tell *how* it becomes obvious; that would be spoiling the fun.)

Comment: This is imho primarily a writing question rather than worldbuilding one. Do you want 1) Have exact copy of 1940s world and take just a litte liberty to change it; 2) Create an alt-history 1940s Earth; 3) Create a world that has no connection to Earth, but looks exactly like 1940s Earth, only with different names; 4) Create a world that is not immediately striking as 1940s Earth, so the reader would have an "A-ha moment" some time later?

Comment: This isn't a worldbuilding question (a question about your fictional world), it is a [writing.se] question (a question about how to help your reader understand what you're doing).  If you don't mind, I'm going to vote to close as not about worldbuilding and then flag the question for the moderators to try and migrate it over to [writing.se].

Comment: I'm voting to keep this open because I think it *is* a worldbuilding question, in a roundabout way. Similar to a question posted a year or two ago in which someone asked (to the effect) "What questions do I need to answer to...?" @Steven consider rephrasing the question in terms of the world it is set in (and unmistakable differences to our own) rather than the framing of the story.

Comment: I am sorry for any trouble or misunderstanding. In response to Alexander's reply above, I think number 3 is the way I was wanting to go. A new world with no connection to earth BUT is almost exactly like 1940's earth only with different names, places and, continents so the reader would not be totally lost from the first page.